# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 168

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a Laravel application. While I had problems with my database I deleted it and remade it. Bad idea.. Tons of problems now with mysql Workbench.

I uninstalled MysqlWorkbench for a couple of times (included files in pc). But every time I try to install my laravel application again I got the following error:

In Connection.php line 664:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) err  
  or from engine' from storage engine (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` i  
  nt unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) n  
  ot null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb  
  4_unicode_ci)                                                                


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) err  
  or from engine' from storage engine
```

This running occurs when running the

```
php artisan migrate
```

command

Comment: Look at [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138505/receiving-general-error-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine) and see if the answer is helpful